# Oracle EntityFramework Core database first - change default type mappings

Tags: oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 2.2 with Oracles EF Core dataprovider - connecting against an existing database.

Is there any possibility to change those mappings as some tables are poorly set up:

- Table A Key is NUMBER(decimal)
- Table B Refrences Table A with a NUMBER(12) (long)

I can't change the tables as it, so I need to adjust my code.

Here is a document where the default mappings are shown :
 https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreREDataTypeMapping.html#GUID-4FF3A9A3-AE49-431B-A4FB-31F8C53FCCF5 

And I'm using asp.net core 2.2 and the latest official oracle ef core package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it:
You have to just remove the database type from the annotation:

```cs
     [Table("TableA", Schema = "Schema")]
      public class TableA
      {
        [Key]
        [Column("KeyColumn")]
        public long KeyColumn { get; set; }
```

Instead of:

```cs
     [Table("TableA", Schema = "Schema")]
      public class TableA
      {
        [Key]
        [Column("KeyColumn", TypeName = "NUMBER")]
        //TypeName = Number isn't compatible with long
        public long KeyColumn{ get; set; }
```